# Frustration with inconsistent Emmet results in VSCode

Tags: emmet, visual-studio-code

I moved to VSCode from ST3 about 6 or 7 months ago now and overall am loving it. But I'm really struggling with inconsistencies in how Emmet/VSCode expands text...

For example: (these examples are as per the [cheat sheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/))

- `fl` should give me `float:left`, but instead i get `flex:` [gif](https://i.imgur.com/FtSKqYB.gifv)
- `m:a` should give me `margin:auto` - although since ST3 i've always used `m-` for this. However in VScode: I get `max-block-size:` [gif](https://i.imgur.com/STor04b.gifv)
- `ttu` should give me `text-transform:uppercase`, but instead I get `text-underline-position:`
- `p20-40` should give me `padding: 20px 40px` but in this case, nothing happens - doesn't recoginize it at all
- `w100p` should give me `width:100%` but again, doesn't even recognize it <-- probably the most annoying one because I use this so often.
- and even HTML borks out quite often: `.div-class` becomes `.div-class<?php` <-- no idea whats going on here... [gif](https://i.imgur.com/rZ9qRCo.gifv)

It almost seems that VSCode has its own built-in Emmet, which is always conflicting with *actual* Emmet. I'll be the first to admit that it might be a conflicting option in my `settings.json`, so here is my settings file:

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "smart",
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true
  },
  "editor.tabCompletion": true,
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary",
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
  "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
  "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
  "editor.autoIndent": true,

  "php.suggest.basic": false,
  "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/php5/bin/php",

  "workbench.colorTheme": "Bimbo Theme",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vs-seti",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "workbench.editor.tabCloseButton": "left",
  "workbench.commandPalette.preserveInput": true,
  "workbench.tips.enabled": false,

  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true
}
```

I have removed settings relating to font sizes and themes etc.

Other Info:

- VSCode Version 1.15.1 (1.15.1)
- [Extensions](https://i.imgur.com/ikGyPmX.jpg)

Would **really** appreciate it if someone who isn't experiencing these issues could share their settings file so I can fix my frustration and carry on loving VSCode?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Emmet is interfering with autocomplete. Try typing any of these commands and execute from command palette `Emmet: Expand Abbreviation`.

- You can remap keybinding for emmet command `editor.emmet.action.expandAbbreviation`
- You can disable autocomplete for css (to show autocomplete when needed `Trigger Suggest` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>)

```json
"[css]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    }
}
```

From version [1.16 August 2017](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_16#_emmet-suggestions-as-snippets) you can move emmet snippets on top and still have autocomplete:

```json
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex that was very useful. Seems a lot of my woes sat in the `editor.quickSuggestions` object. Appreciate your help